# Algorithm to find all possible solutions from an array of array

Tags: objective-c, arrays, algorithm, loops

What is the best algorithm to find all possible words from an array of array of character.

Here an example :
From this array : `[[A],[B,C,D],[E,F],[G,H]]`
I need in return an array of the 12 ordered possibilities `[[A,B,E,G],[A,C,E,G], ... , [A,D,F,H]]`

Do you know how to implement this algorithm ? If you know it and you provide an example in any language (C,JAVA,Javascript, ...), feel free to share because it's been a day I try to find it ...

Here how I tries to implement it ("array" is an array of array of char):

```
+ (NSArray*) possibleReading:(NSMutableArray*)array {
    int nbPossibilities = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) {
        nbPossibilities *=[[array objectAtIndex:i] count];
    }

    NSMutableArray *possArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nbPossibilities];
    for (int i=0; i < nbPossibilities; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];
        [possArr addObject:innerArray];
    }

    for (int i=0; i< [array count]; i++) {
        //
        for(int nbPoss = 0; nbPoss < nbPossibilities; nbPoss++) {
            NSMutableArray * arr = [possArr objectAtIndex:nbPoss];
            NSNumber * num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:nbPoss % [[array objectAtIndex:i] count]];
            NSString * literal = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:[num intValue]];
            [arr insertObject:literal atIndex:i];
        }

    }
    return possArr;
}
```

Comment: and after a long day, you've got any output to show us? [I expect you're not new around here, so...]

Comment: It's 1*3*2*2 = 12 possibilities - not 16, the term you're looking for is called "Cartesian product".

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20935315/java-generate-all-possible-combinations-of-a-given-list

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum question updated thank you

Comment: @SouravGhosh I added what I'm stuck at ... (It's not working .. i have duplicate possibilities ...)

Comment: I found a Objective-C implementation in this answer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/8265318/1041757

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thank you Benjamin ! Cartesian product was the magic word ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Objectiv-C**

```
   + (NSArray *) cartesianProductOfArrays(NSArray *arrays) {
        int arraysCount = arrays.count;
        unsigned long resultSize = 1;
        for (NSArray *array in arrays)
            resultSize *= array.count;
        NSMutableArray *product = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:resultSize];
        for (unsigned long i = 0; i < resultSize; ++i) {
            NSMutableArray *cross = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:arraysCount];
            [product addObject:cross];
            unsigned long n = i;
            for (NSArray *array in arrays) {
                [cross addObject:[array objectAtIndex:n % array.count]];
                n /= array.count;
            }
        }
        return product;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easiest to do this using a recursive method.

#### Java code

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class CartesianProductCalculator {

    private char[][] result;
    private char[][] sets;
    private char[] currentSet;
    private int index;

    public char[][] calculateProduct(char[][] sets) {
        index = 0;
        // calculate size of result
        int resultSize = 1;
        this.sets = sets;
        for (char[] set : sets) {
            resultSize *= set.length;
        }
        result = new char[resultSize][];
        currentSet = new char[sets.length];
        calculateProduct(sets.length-1);
        return result;
    }

    // fills result from right to left
    public void calculateProduct(int setIndex) {
        if (setIndex >= 0) {
            for (char c : sets[setIndex]) {
                currentSet[setIndex] = c;
                calculateProduct(setIndex-1);
            }
        } else {
            result[index++] = Arrays.copyOf(currentSet, currentSet.length);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[][] input = {{'A'},{'B','C','D'},{'E','F'},{'G','H'}};
        CartesianProductCalculator productCalculator = new CartesianProductCalculator();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(productCalculator.calculateProduct(input)));
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**C**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print(int size, char *array[size], int indexs[size]){
    char result[size+1];
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        result[i] = array[i][indexs[i]];
    result[size] = 0;
    puts(result);
}

int countUp(int size, int indexs[size], int lens[size]){
    int i = size -1;
    while(i >= 0){
        indexs[i] += 1;// count up
        if(indexs[i] == lens[i])
            indexs[i--] = 0;
        else
            break;
    }
    return i >= 0;
}

void find_all(int size, char *array[size]){
    int lens[size];
    int indexs[size];
    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < size; ++i){//initialize
        lens[i] = strlen(array[i]);
        indexs[i] = 0;
    }

    do{
        print(size, array, indexs);
    }while(countUp(size, indexs, lens));
}

int main(void){
    char *array[] = { "A", "BCD", "EF", "GH" };
    int size = sizeof(array)/sizeof(*array);

    find_all(size, array);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can remove duplicate entries in inner array objects before executing method then you won't get duplicate words in result array.

```
- (NSArray*) possibleReading:(NSMutableArray*)array {
    int nbPossibilities = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < [array count]; i++) 
     {


        NSArray *cleanedArray = [[NSSet setWithArray:[array objectAtIndex:i]] allObjects];
        [array replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:cleanedArray];
         nbPossibilities *=[[array objectAtIndex:i] count];
    }

    NSMutableArray *possArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:nbPossibilities];
    for (int i=0; i < nbPossibilities; i++) {
        NSMutableArray *innerArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[array count]];
        [possArr addObject:innerArray];
    }

    for (int i=0; i< [array count]; i++) {
        //
        for(int nbPoss = 0; nbPoss < nbPossibilities; nbPoss++) {
            NSMutableArray * arr = [possArr objectAtIndex:nbPoss];
            NSNumber * num = [NSNumber numberWithInt:nbPoss % [[array objectAtIndex:i] count]];
            NSString * literal = [[array objectAtIndex:i] objectAtIndex:[num intValue]];
            [arr insertObject:literal atIndex:i];
        }

    }
    return possArr;
}
```