# How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays

Tags: php, arrays, combinations, iteration

I'im trying to find all combinations of items in several arrays.
The number of arrays is random (this can be 2, 3, 4, 5...).
The number of elements in each array is random too...

For exemple, I have the 3 arrays :

```
$arrayA = array('A1','A2','A3');
$arrayB = array('B1','B2','B3');
$arrayC = array('C1','C2');
```

I would like to generate an array with 3 x 3 x 2 = 18 combinations :

- A1, B1, C1
- A1, B1, C2
- A1, B2, C1
- A1, B2, C2
- A1, B3, C1
- A1, B3, C2
- A2, B1, C1
- A2, B1, C2
  ...

The problem is to create a function with a variable number of source arrays...

Comment: You always want one element from *each* array?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Here is recursive solution:

```
function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }

    // get combinations from subsequent arrays
    $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

    $result = array();

    // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                array($v, $t);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(
    combinations(
        array(
            array('A1','A2','A3'), 
            array('B1','B2','B3'), 
            array('C1','C2')
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: how should I change this function if I want the unique combinations for duplicated arrays? For instance, if I have array('A1','A2','A3'), array('A1','A2','A3'), array('C1','C2') and I want as result "A1, A2, C1", "A1, A3, C1", etc, but NO "A1, A1, C1" ? Also (if I'm not asking too much ;) , {"A1", "A2", "C1"} it's the same that {"A2", "A1", "C1"} so I only want 1 combination?

Comment: @AlexAngelico - and for anyone else with same question, see array_unique, http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: It's an old answer. But the solution did not work as expected if pass a single array like ```[['A1','A2','A3']]```

Comment: it doesn't work for single array if you need a good solution work for me very well https://stackoverflow.com/a/76196962/10500869

Answer (score 21):

This code besides simplicity, get all combinations of multiple arrays and preserves keys.

```
function get_combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($property_values as $property_key => $property_value) {
                $tmp[] = $result_item + array($property_key => $property_value);
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

**Exemple:**

```
Array
(
    Array
    (
        '1' => 'White',
        '2' => 'Green',
        '3' => 'Blue'
    ),
    Array
    (
        '4' =>' Small',
        '5' => 'Big'
    )
)
```

**Will return:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [1] => White
        [4] =>  Small
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [1] => White
        [5] => Big
    )
    [2] => Array
    (
        [2] => Green
        [4] =>  Small
    )
    [3] => Array
    (
        [2] => Green
        [5] => Big
    )
    [4] => Array
    (
        [3] => Blue
        [4] =>  Small
    )
    [5] => Array
    (
        [3] => Blue
        [5] => Big
    )
)
```

Answer (score 18):

This is a cartesian product, and I just [asked the same question not too long ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8176719/algorithm-generating-all-combinations-from-items-that-must-be-chosen-in-sequen). Here is the [algorithm that is posted on the PHP website](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

```
function array_cartesian_product($arrays)
{
    $result = array();
    $arrays = array_values($arrays);
    $sizeIn = sizeof($arrays);
    $size = $sizeIn > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    foreach ($arrays as $array)
        $size = $size * sizeof($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i ++)
    {
        $result[$i] = array();
        for ($j = 0; $j < $sizeIn; $j ++)
            array_push($result[$i], current($arrays[$j]));
        for ($j = ($sizeIn -1); $j >= 0; $j --)
        {
            if (next($arrays[$j]))
                break;
            elseif (isset ($arrays[$j]))
                reset($arrays[$j]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: The link to the PHP website doesn't apparently lead anything about this function. Could you give an example of invoking it?

Comment: This function takes over 2.5 times as long as Lolo's function to process the same array.

Answer (score 11):

I like this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33259643/3163536
but to answer the actual question (which assumes that **the number of elements of each combination should be equal to the number of incoming arrays**) the function should be modified:

```
function getCombinations(...$arrays)
    {
        $result = [[]];
        foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
            $tmp = [];
            foreach ($result as $result_item) {
                foreach ($property_values as $property_value) {
                    $tmp[] = array_merge($result_item, [$property => $property_value]);
                }
            }
            $result = $tmp;
        }
        return $result;
    }
```

The usage:

```
$arrayA = array('A1','A2','A3');
$arrayB = array('B1','B2','B3');
$arrayC = array('C1','C2');

print_r(getCombinations($arrayA, $arrayB, $arrayC));
```

The result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C2
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C2
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C1
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C2
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C1
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C2
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C1
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this question is old, but I got the same issue today and decided to give the new Generator a try:

```
function generateCombinations(array $array) {
    foreach (array_pop($array) as $value) {
        if (count($array)) {
            foreach (generateCombinations($array) as $combination) {
                yield array_merge([$value], $combination);
            };
        } else {
            yield [$value];
        }
    }
}

foreach (generateCombinations(['a' => ['A'], 'b' => ['B'], 'c' => ['C', 'D'], 'd' => ['E', 'F', 'G']]) as $c) {
        var_dump($c);
    }
```

Result:

```
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(1) "E"
[1]=>
string(1) "C"
[2]=>
string(1) "B"
[3]=>
string(1) "A"
}
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(1) "E"
[1]=>
string(1) "D"
[2]=>
string(1) "B"
[3]=>
string(1) "A"
}
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(1) "F"
[1]=>
string(1) "C"
[2]=>
string(1) "B"
[3]=>
string(1) "A"
}
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(1) "F"
[1]=>
string(1) "D"
[2]=>
string(1) "B"
[3]=>
string(1) "A"
}
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(1) "G"
[1]=>
string(1) "C"
[2]=>
string(1) "B"
[3]=>
string(1) "A"
}
array(4) {
[0]=>
string(1) "G"
[1]=>
string(1) "D"
[2]=>
string(1) "B"
[3]=>
string(1) "A"
}
```

Comment: When the order doesn't matter, it is a Combination.
When the order does matter it is a Permutation.
In this case, it's a Permutation and not a Combination.

Comment: this is the most simple solution

Comment: is there a way to achieve this ?
`array(4) {
'd' =>
string(1) "E"
'c' =>
string(1) "C"
'b' =>
string(1) "B"
'a' =>
string(1) "A"
}`

Comment: workaround for my question: 
 create array like that `['a' => [['key' => 'a', 'value' => 'A'], ['key' => 'a', 'value' => 'n']]]`

Comment: Just in case someone wants the first array's items to appear at the first use `array_shift` instead of `array_pop` at line 2.

Answer (score 5):

One more idea:

```
$ar = [
    'a' => [1,2,3],
    'b' => [4,5,6],
    'c' => [7,8,9]
];

$counts = array_map("count", $ar);
$total = array_product($counts);
$res = [];

$combinations = [];
$curCombs = $total;

foreach ($ar as $field => $vals) {
    $curCombs = $curCombs / $counts[$field];
    $combinations[$field] = $curCombs;
}

for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    foreach ($ar as $field => $vals) {
        $res[$i][$field] = $vals[($i / $combinations[$field]) % $counts[$field]];
    }
}

var_dump($res);
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution with generators and array unpacking:

```
function combinations(array $arrays): iterable {
    if ($arrays === []) {
        yield [];
        return;
    }

    $head = array_shift($arrays);

    foreach ($head as $elem) {
        foreach (self::combinations($arrays) as $combination) {
            yield [$elem, ...$combination];
        }
    }
}
```

Try it here: https://3v4l.org/Y8clG

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C2
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => A1
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C2
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C1
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C2
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C1
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C1
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => A2
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C2
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C1
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B1
            [2] => C2
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C1
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B2
            [2] => C2
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C1
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => A3
            [1] => B3
            [2] => C2
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a code that generates unique combinations from a set of numbers.

If you have a list of numbers, like `1,3,4,7,12` you can generate sets of `X` numbers, all unique, no repetitive.

The first function works in `PHP 7.4` or higher, and the second one uses keys to store the values. Both work very well based on the benchmark.

```php
function get_combos74($map, $size, &$generated = [], $loop = 1, $i = 0, $prefix = [])
{
    if ($loop == 1) {
        sort($map);
    }

    for (; $i < count($map); $i++) {
        if ($loop < $size) {
            get_combos74($map, $size, $generated, $loop + 1, $i + 1, [...$prefix, $map[$i]]);
        } else {
            $generated[] = [...$prefix, $map[$i]];
        }
    }

    return $generated;
}

function get_combosSTR($map, $size, &$generated = [], $loop = 1, $i = 0, $prefix = '')
{
    if ($loop == 1) {
        sort($map);
    }

    for (; $i < count($map); $i++) {
        if ($loop < $size) {
            get_combosSTR($map, $size, $generated, $loop + 1, $i + 1, "$prefix{$map[$i]}:");
        } else {
            $generated["$prefix{$map[$i]}"] = 0;
        }
    }

    return $generated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved upon the solution given by @mr1031011 to allow the optional preservation of keys

```
/**
 * Generate an array of permutations from a given array[array[options]]
 * e.g.
 * ['foo' => [null, 'a'], 'bar' => ['b']]
 *
 * will generate:
 * [null, 'b']
 * ['a', 'b']
 *
 * or with preserveKeys = true:
 * ['foo' => null,'bar' => 'b']
 * ['foo' => 'a','bar' => 'b']
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param bool  $preserveKeys
 *
 * @return Generator
 */
function generatePermutations(array $array, bool $preserveKeys = false): Generator
{
    if ($preserveKeys) {
        end($array);
        $key = key($array);
    }

    foreach (array_pop($array) as $value) {
        $item = isset($key) ? [$key => $value] : [$value];

        if (!count($array)) {
            yield $item;
            continue;
        }

        foreach (generatePermutations($array, $preserveKeys) as $combination) {
            yield array_merge($item, $combination);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I got this from O'Relly (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/php-cookbook/1565926811/ch04s25.html),

```
function pc_array_power_set($array) {
// initialize by adding the empty set
$results = array(array( ));

foreach ($array as $element)
    foreach ($results as $combination)
        array_push($results, array_merge(array($element), $combination));



   return $results;
}
```

Then call it using,

```
$set = array('A', 'B', 'C');
$power_set = pc_array_power_set($set);
```

That should do the trick!