# How to compute the cartesian power of a range of characters?

Tags: php, string, range, cartesian-product

I would like to make a function that is able to generate a list of letters and optional numbers using a-z,0-9.

```
$output = array();
foreach(range('a','z') as $i) {
    foreach(range('a','z') as $j) { 
        foreach(range('a','z') as $k) { 
            $output[] =$i.$j.$k;
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

example:

```
 myfunction($include, $length)
```

usage something like this:

```
 myfunction('a..z,0..9', 3);
```

output:

```
000
001
...
aaa
aab
...
zzz
```

The output would have every possible combination of the letters, and numbers.

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to accomplish? And did you really mean to tag "PHP4"?

Comment: PHP4, PHP5 whatever code will work.

Comment: For future reference, what you are trying to do here is generate the [cartesian power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product#Cartesian_square_and_Cartesian_power) of a set of characters. With the added detail that you also want a convenient notation to describe this set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setting the stage

First, a function that expands strings like `"0..9"` to `"0123456789"` using [`range`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php):

```
function expand_pattern($pattern) {
    $bias = 0;
    $flags = PREG_SET_ORDER | PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE;
    preg_match_all('/(.)\.\.(.)/', $pattern, $matches, $flags);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        $range = implode('', range($match[1][0], $match[2][0]));
        $pattern = substr_replace(
            $pattern, 
            $range, 
            $bias + $match[1][1],
            $match[2][1] - $match[1][1] + 1);
        $bias += strlen($range) - 4; // 4 == length of "X..Y"
    }

    return $pattern;
}
```

It handles any number of expandable patterns and takes care to preserve their position inside your source string, so for example

```
expand_pattern('abc0..4def5..9')
```

will return `"abc01234def56789"`.

### Calculating the result all at once

Now that we can do this expansion easily, here's a function that calculates cartesian products given a string of allowed characters and a length:

```
function cartesian($pattern, $length) {
    $choices = strlen($pattern);
    $indexes = array_fill(0, $length, 0);
    $results = array();
    $resets = 0;

    while ($resets != $length) {
        $result = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $result .= $pattern[$indexes[$i]];
        }
        $results[] = $result;

        $resets = 0;
        for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0 && ++$indexes[$i] == $choices; --$i) {
            $indexes[$i] = 0;
            ++$resets;
        }
    }

    return $results;
}
```

So for example, to get the output described in the question you would do

```
$options = cartesian(expand_pattern('a..z0..9'), 3);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/qf8qQH)** (I limited the expansion length to 2 so that the output doesn't explode).

### Generating the result on the fly

Since the result set can be extremely large (it grows exponentially with `$length`), producing it all at once can turn out to be prohibitive. In that case it is possible to rewrite the code so that it returns each value in turn (iterator-style), which has become super easy with PHP 5.5 because of [generators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.overview.php):

```
function cartesian($pattern, $length) {
    $choices = strlen($pattern);
    $indexes = array_fill(0, $length, 0);
    $resets = 0;

    while ($resets != $length) {
        $result = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < $length; ++$i) {
            $result .= $pattern[$indexes[$i]];
        }
        yield $result;

        $resets = 0;
        for ($i = $length - 1; $i >= 0 && ++$indexes[$i] == $choices; --$i) {
            $indexes[$i] = 0;
            ++$resets;
        }
    }
}
```

**[See it in action](http://3v4l.org/gqdeC)**.

Answer (score 0):

See this answer for a code that produces all possible combinations:
 https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567199/1800369

You just need to add the `$length` parameter to limit the combinations size.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use a recursive function

assuming you mean it can be any number of levels deep, you can use a recursive function to generate an array of the permutations e.g.:

```
/** 
 * take the range of characters, and generate an array of all permutations
 *
 * @param array $range      range of characters to itterate over
 * @param array $array      input array - operated on by reference
 * @param int $depth        how many chars to put in the resultant array should be
 * @param int $currentDepth internal variable to track how nested the current call is
 * @param string $prefix    internal variable to know what to prefix the current string with
* @return array             permutations
*/
function foo($range, &$array, $depth = 1, $currentDepth = 0, $prefix = "") {
    $start = !$currentDepth;
    $currentDepth++;

    if ($currentDepth > $depth) {
        return;
    }   

    foreach($range as $char) {
        if ($currentDepth === $depth) {
            $array[] = $prefix . $char;
            continue;
        }   

        foo($range, $array, $depth, $currentDepth, $prefix . $char);
    }   

    if ($start) {
        return $array;
    }
```

With the above function, initialize the return variable and call it:

```
$return = array();
echo implode(foo(range('a', 'z'), $return, 3), "\n");
```

And you're output will be all three char combinations from aaa, to zzz:

```
aaa
aab
...
zzy
zzz
```

The numeric parameter determins how recursive the function is:

```
$return = array();
echo implode(foo(range('a', 'z'), $return, 1), "\n");
a
b
c
...
```

[Here's a live example](http://3v4l.org/Dhmk7).

Answer (score -1):

```
$number= range(0, 9);
 $letters = range('a', 'z');
$array= array_merge($number, $letters);
//print_r($array);

for($a=0;$a<count($array);$a++){
    for($b=0;$b<count($array);$b++){
        for($c=0;$c<count($array);$c++){
                echo $array[$a].$array[$b].$array[$c]."<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

tested and working :)

Comment: oh... you updated your question... this code made all posible combination from 0 to z....

Comment: Thanks but original question still had optional length.  This does what I had before except it has the range merged which I had not though of! :P