# how do i programmatically create unique codes like ABCD1234 in PHP

Tags: php, math, unique, probability

i need to programmatically  create a unique code combinations of four characters and four numeric identifiers such as ABCD1234. so how do i do it any how many possible codes are there in this combination.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about combinatorics.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorics

Comment: In which language you want to create this combination?

Comment: Im sorry to say, Im a C# and VB programmer.

Comment: four of what set of characters, may be relevant...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson Any set of characters right from A to Z.

Comment: @ArifAnsari can you please suggest me how to do it in C#?

Comment: This might get you started. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942318/php-generate-all-combinations-from-given-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're only using uppercase letters:

There are 26 letters in the english alphabet, and 10 digits from 0-9.  The number of combinations of four letters followed by 4 digits is 26 <sup>4</sup> * 10 <sup>4</sup>, which comes out to 4569760000.

In php, you can generate it like so:

```
function generateCode()
{
    $code = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
        $code .= chr(mt_rand(65, 90)); // A-Z
    }
    for ($i = 0; $i < 4; ++$i) {
        $code .= mt_rand(0, 9);
    }
    return $code;
}
```

Comment: thats 4billion combinations :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in C#, in such way;

```
namespace GenerateRandom
{
    public class MainClass
    {
        private static Random random = new Random();
        public static int RandomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }

        public static string RandomString(int size, bool lowerCase)
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            Random random = new Random();
            char ch;
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                ch = Convert.ToChar(Convert.ToInt32(Math.Floor(26 * random.NextDouble() + 65)));
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
            if (lowerCase)
                return builder.ToString().ToLower();
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        public static string GetPassword()
        {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            builder.Append(RandomString(4, false));
            builder.Append(RandomNumber(1000, 9999));
            return builder.ToString();
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            //Each time it will be changing.
            string randomValue = GetPassword();//YOUR FINAL OUTPUT WILL BE IN randomValue variable.
        }
    }
}
```