# How can I return all combinations of a given string? (ex. 'foo bar' = bar, bar_foo, foo)

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, combinations

**This question is not a duplicate of the suggested question above.** The title may *sound* similar, but its answer does not in any way lead to the result described in the question below.

---

I'm having a hard time recursively iterating through an array of unknown length to create unique combinations of strings. Can you help?

The goal is to take a string like `foo bar` and create unique combinations from this string:

```
foo
bar
bar_foo (alphabetized to make unique combinations, not permutations)
```

Another example:

`car bar add` should return:

```
add
add_bar
add_car
add_bar_car
bar
bar_car
car
```

Here's my progress:

```
function string_builder($length) {
    $arrWords = array('add','bar','car','dew','eat','fat','gym','hey','ink','jet','key','log','mad','nap','odd','pal','qat','ram','saw','tan','urn','vet','wed','xis','yap','zoo');
    $arr = array();
    for ($i=0; $i < $length; $i++) { 
        $arr[] = $arrWords[$i];
    }
    return implode(' ', $arr);
}
function get_combinations($string) {
    $combinations = array(); // put all combinations here
    $arr = explode(' ',$string);
    $arr = array_unique($arr); // only unique words are important
    sort($arr); // alphabetize to make unique combinations easier (not permutations)
    $arr = array_values($arr); // reset keys
    for ($i=0; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        // this is where I'm stuck
        // how do I loop recursively through all possible combinations of an array?
    }
    return $combinations;
}
// Test it!
for ($i=1; $i < 26; $i++) { 
    $string = string_builder($i);
    $combinations = get_combinations($string);
    echo $i . " words\t" . count($combinations) . " combinations\t" . $string . "\n";
    // print_r($combinations);
}
```

---

Another attempt:

```
function getCombinations2($str, $min_length = 2) {
    $words = explode(' ', $str);
    $combinations = array();
    $len = count($words);
    for ($a = $min_length; $a <= $min_length; $a++) {
        for ($pos = 0; $pos < $len; $pos ++) {
            if(($pos + $a -1) < $len) {
                $tmp = array_slice($words, $pos, $a);
                sort($tmp);
                $tmp = implode('_',$tmp);
                $combinations[] = $tmp;
            }
        }
    }
    $combinations = array_unique($combinations);
    return $combinations;
}
```

You can know you're successful when you print out the combinations and look for a couple combinations that should be there (for example, "fat_zoo","car_tan"). Both of my attempts will show several of these, but never all of them.

Comment: What exactly do you want? Do you want all possible cominations of all syllables? How many syllables do you want each word to have?

Comment: @MCEmperor, just words. `explode(' ',$str)` is fine.

Comment: I thought permutations cared about order? I don't want `bar_foo`,`bar_bar`, `foo_bar` and `foo_foo`. I only want one of those (`bar_foo`, since it's easier to alphabetize).

Comment: Combinations disregard order and therefore ABC and CBA are the same. Permutations care about order and therefore see the two as distinct. When order matters, different orders are different subsets, not the other way around

Comment: Thanks Anthony. I want to treat `ABC` and `CBA` the same. Thus the move to sort the result alphabetically to ensure that `CBA` will never show up if `ABC` is included.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php generate all combinations from given array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17942318/php-generate-all-combinations-from-given-array)

Comment: @CBroe, I appreciate your help, but the accepted answer there does not yield the result requested in this question.

Answer (score 3):

What you are searching is pretty easy to build up (and explain) using binary numbers.

Each position in the binary *word* should indicate whether a certain word out of the array is appended - or not.

let's assume, you are having an array made out of two words:

```
$words = ["foo","bar"];
```

You are now expecting the combinations

```
foo
bar
bar_foo
```

in binary this can be represented as

```
1 0
0 1
1 1
```

With three words `$words = ["foo","bar", "baz"];` it would be the combinations

```
foo
bar
baz
foo_bar
foo_baz
bar_baz
foo_bar_baz
```

which can be interpreted as

```
1 0 0
0 1 0
0 0 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 1 
1 1 1
```

(ignoring alphabetic sorting as of now)

let's move those binary numbers into a concrete order and look at the decimal value of them:

```
0 0 1 // dec 1
0 1 0 // dec 2
0 1 1 // dec 3
1 0 0 // dec 4
1 0 1 // dec 5
1 1 0 // dec 6
1 1 1 // dec 7
```

*To Note*: The number of elements you want to generate is `(2^n)-1`, where n is your number of words.

And that's basically all you need to do:

- Iterate from `1` to `(2^n)-1`.
- Take the binary version of that decimal number as "array-indexes".
- Append elements where index is "1".

php:

```
print_r(get_combinations("car bar add"));

function get_combinations($str) {
    $words = explode(' ',$str);
    $elements = pow(2, count($words))-1;

    $result = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i<=$elements; $i++){
        $bin = decbin($i);
        $padded_bin = str_pad($bin, count($words), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $res = array();
        for ($k=0; $k<count($words); $k++){
            //append element, if binary position says "1";
            if ($padded_bin[$k]==1){
                $res[] = $words[$k];
            }
        }

        sort($res);
        $result[] = implode("_", $res);
    }
    sort($result);
    return $result;
}
```

results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => add
    [1] => bar
    [2] => bar_add
    [3] => car
    [4] => car_add
    [5] => car_bar
    [6] => car_bar_add
)
```

**You can sort the array `$res` alphabetically before imploding it.**

---

Limited to length `3`:

```
print_r(get_combinations("car bar add"));

function get_combinations($str) {
    $words = explode(' ',$str);
    $elements = pow(2, count($words))-1;

    $result = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i<=$elements; $i++){
        $bin = decbin($i);
        $padded_bin = str_pad($bin, count($words), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $res = array();
        for ($k=0; $k<count($words); $k++){
           //break, if maximum length is reached.
           if (count($res) == 3){
             break;
           }           

           //append element, if binary position says "1";
            if ($padded_bin[$k]==1){
                $res[] = $words[$k];
            }
        }

        sort($res);

        //check result array if combination already exists before inserting.
        $res_string =implode("_", $res);
        if (!in_array($res_string, $result)){ 
          $result[] = $res_string;
        } 
    }
    sort($result);
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: This works! But wow is this a memory hog. It loads up to 10 words well, but starts to really slow down as I loop through larger strings. Any tips to keep it from exhausting too much memory?

Comment: I think this is the *best* solution you can get. For a required output of "X" Elements you are iterating "X" times - Maybe some tweaking on the repeated access to `count()` - but that's all you can do to improve performance.

Comment: How about this... how can I limit the length of results that are returned?  For example, include all combinations less than `3` words long? So running this on a string 26 words long will still return `xis_yap_zoo`. Trying to save memory. I tried limiting the `for` loops but it's not working. I don't understand where I can stop the loop `if > max`.

Comment: @Ryan: Limit the max length of the array `$res` to 3 by using a `break;` - But this will produce duplicates - so check the array `$result` before inserting.

Comment: Hmmm, but this still stores everything in memory. Even limiting to 3 on 25 words times out for me.

Comment: @Ryan: 25 words (remember `(2^n)-1`) makes `33.554.431` combinations... That takes a serious amount of memory and time of course.

Comment: Right, but if we get rid of all combinations with more than 3 words, there should be a whole lot less, correct? How can I only loop through this much much smaller subset?

Comment: Wow. I'm going to have to do some thinking about how to make this work. These numbers are larger than I expected.

Comment: @Ryan: Wait, that was wrong... it's lesser (but still a huge number)

Comment: Okay, it would be `bin(25,1)+bin(25,2)+bin(25,3)` (`+` not `*`) combinations. So only 2625 combinations - **BUT** you cannot really *cherry-pick* the valid combinations only. Some sort of iteration is required...

Comment: @Ryan Nope. it's `bin(n, 1)+bin(n,2)+...+bin(n,m)` Where `n` is your number of words and `m` is the maximum length desired. See here (http://dantheseal.com/test.php) : 7 words, max length 3 -> 63 combinations. (equals `bin(7,1)+bin(7,2)+bin(7,3)` - spoken: Every combination of 1 out of 7 + every combination of 2 out of 7 + every combination of 3 out of 7)

Comment: looking at the example array you *could* iterate over only the relevant items by generating a custom "overflow" (i.e. `"1_2_7" +1 = "1_3`" - check back tomorrow evening, if i find some time i might update the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.5 you can use generators to eliminate your memory problem. It also lowers the overall execution time a bit.

```
Generators
15: 256kb, 0.48s
16: 256kb, 0.90s
19: 256kb, 7.76s

Original
15:  5.75mb, 0.49s
16: 17.25mb, 0.99s
19: 86.24mb, 8.58s
```

Based on dognose's function you can replace the $result[] assignment to yield $res instead. Rather than running through the whole loop and returning a gigantic array, the function steps through it one by one, returning (yielding) a single element each time.

```
function combo_gen($str) 
{
    $words = explode(' ',$str);
    $elements = pow(2, count($words))-1;

    $result = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i<=$elements; $i++)
    {
        $bin = decbin($i);
        $padded_bin = str_pad($bin, count($words), "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);

        $res = array();
        for ($k=0; $k<count($words); $k++){
            //append element, if binary position says "1";
            if ($padded_bin[$k]==1){
                $res[] = $words[$k];
            }
        }

        sort($res);

        $res = implode("_", $res);

        yield $res;
    }
}

foreach(combo_gen('one two three') as $item) {
  //stuff
}}
```

Comment: What if I don't have the ability to use PHP 5.5? (PHP 5.4)

Comment: Nice improvement in terms of memory! - but I think that for the desired input of 25 words - not the memory is the major problem - but the time it takes. (however it's never wrong to imrpove resource consumption everywhere)

Comment: @dognose yeah, unfortunately that's true. Though it's still a good example to show how generators can make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a more elegant solution, but I did it with 2 functions.

The getCombosOfLength function gives every $intLength combination within the array. The GetCombos function just runs GetCombosOfLength for each length that you want. This works very well to generate all combinations that are 1-5 items. If you run it for all 25-item combinations, it has some problems.

```
$a = array("c", "b", "f", "v", "g", "e", "h", "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "p", "o", "r", "a", "q", "s", "t", "u", "w", "x", "y", "z");
$b = getCombos($a, 5);

print "<pre>\n";
print_r($b);

function getCombos($arrInput, $intMax = null) {
    sort($arrInput);
    if (is_null($intMax)) $intMax = count($arrInput);
    $arrOutput = array();
    for ($i = $intMax; $i > 0; $i--) {
        $arrReturn = getCombosOfLength($arrInput, $i);
        for ($j = 0; $j < count($arrReturn); $j++)  $arrOutput[] = $arrReturn[$j];
    }
    return $arrOutput;
}

function getCombosOfLength($arrInput, $intLength) {
    $arrOutput = array();
    if ($intLength == 1) {
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrInput); $i++) $arrOutput[] = array($arrInput[$i]);
        return $arrOutput;
    }
    $arrShift = $arrInput;
    while (count($arrShift)) {
        $x = array_shift($arrShift);
        $arrReturn = getCombosOfLength($arrShift, $intLength - 1);
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($arrReturn); $i++) {
            array_unshift($arrReturn[$i], $x);
            $arrOutput[] = $arrReturn[$i];
        }
    }
    return $arrOutput;
}
```