# Get all 2-word combinations from a string of words

Tags: php, combinations, cpu-word

Here, i have the string....

```
$string = "Modern Country Kitchen";
```

I want split that string **Word by Word** wiht provision **min 2 word**, i want result like this...

```
$string1 = "Modern Country";
$string2 = "Country Kitchen";
$string3 = "Modern Kitchen";
```

How the logic code to make it be, what the php function should i used...?

So far my logic only be explode the string using explode() function..

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068895/2943403

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, let's start with a way to retrieve every combination/permutation of an array:

```
function getAllCombinations(array $input)
{
    if (count($input) > 0)
    {
        foreach (getAllCombinations(array_slice($input, 1)) as $combination)
        {
            foreach (array_keys($input) as $index) {
                yield array_merge(
                    array_slice($combination, 0, $index),
                    [$input[0]],
                    array_slice($combination, $index)
                );
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        yield $input;
    }
}
```

See it work here:

```
php > foreach (getAllCombinations2([1, 2]) as $combination) {
php { var_dump($combination);
php { }
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(2)
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(2)
  [1]=>
  int(1)
}
php >
```

Now we need to turn our input string into an array (you're right about `explode()`!):

```
$string = "Modern Country Kitchen";
$words = explode(" ", $string);
```

Now it looks like this:

```
php > var_dump($words);
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Modern"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "Country"
  [2]=>
  string(7) "Kitchen"
}
```

So, now we can get an array of all combinations of these three words:

```
$wordCombinations = iterator_to_array(getAllCombinations($words));
```

Seen:

```
php > var_dump(iterator_to_array(getAllCombinations2($words)));
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "Modern"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "Country"
    [2]=>
    string(7) "Kitchen"
  }

...
```

Now, let's convert the combinations back into strings:

```
$combinations = array_map(function ($words) {
    return implode(" ", $words);
}, $wordCombinations);
```

Now let's look at our end result:

```
php > var_dump($combinations);
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "Modern Country Kitchen"
  [1]=>
  string(22) "Country Modern Kitchen"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "Country Kitchen Modern"
  [3]=>
  string(22) "Modern Kitchen Country"
  [4]=>
  string(22) "Kitchen Modern Country"
  [5]=>
  string(22) "Kitchen Country Modern"
}
php > var_dump($combinations[0]);
string(22) "Modern Country Kitchen"
```

Comment: Do this code realy work.. ?

I got error because i can't use "yield" function.. its run on php 5.5 version right...? while i use older than that....

Comment: Oh, yes, this is PHP 5.5+ sorry