# Get all possible combinations of three arrays without duplicates

Tags: php, arrays

I've got three dynamically filled arrays. It's possible that only one or two arrays have data.

```
$array1 = array(
    [0] => 100GB
    [1] => 500GB
)

$array2 = array(
    [0] => black
    [1] => yellow
    [2] => green
)

$array1 = array(
    [0] => 2.5"
)
```

No I need to combine them into a new array that includes all possible variations

```
$variations = array(
    [0] => 100GB - black - 2.5"
    [1] => 100GB - yellow - 2.5"
    [2] => 100GB - green - 2.5"
    [3] => 500GB - black - 2.5"
    [4] => 500GB - yellow - 2.5"
    [5] => 500GB - green - 2.5"
)
```

Until now I didn't find a way to do this.
Can someone please help me?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this easily with foreach loops:

```
$array1 = array('100GB', '500GB');
$array2 = array('black', 'yellow', 'green');
$array3 = array('2.5');

$combinations = array();
foreach ($array1 as $i) {
  foreach ($array2 as $j) {
    foreach ($array3 as $k) {
      $combinations[] = $i.' - '.$j.' - '.$k;
    }
  }
}

echo implode("\n", $combinations);
```

**Edit:** To handle empty arrays, you could use this function:

```
function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }

    // get combinations from subsequent arrays
    $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

    $result = array();

    // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                array($v, $t);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

This function was taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8567199) answer, so credit goes to the author. You can then call this `combinations` function this way:

```
$array1 = array('100GB', '500GB');
$array2 = array();
$array3 = array('2.5');

$arrays = array_values(array_filter(array($array1, $array2, $array3)));
$combinations = combinations($arrays);

foreach ($combinations as &$combination) {
  $combination = implode(' - ', $combination);
}

echo implode("\n", $combinations);
```

This outputs:

```
100GB - 2.5
500GB - 2.5
```

Comment: hi, thank you that'S solving it partly. The problem is, if there's no array3 thann $result is empty. how can I avoid this?

Comment: perhapse you can also have an eye on here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24499295/dynamically-create-new-arrays-fill-each-with-specials-values-from-first-array-a

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use nested loops. One loop on the first array, one on the second, one on the third, and join the items from each array, and push the result onto a new array.

Comment: hi, could you please show this with an example code?