# How to find all unique combinations per each elements in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, multidimensional-array

I would know how to find all combinations per each element in a multidimensional array looking like this one :

```
[
    ['1a', '1b',], 
    ['2a','2b','2c',], 
    ['3a',], 
    ['4a','4b',], 
    ['5a','5b','5c','5d',]
]
```

The output must be a table.
I found some Algo but only to get all combinations of a single dimensional array.

It Doesn't have to get all the the combinations in all possible directions.
For example the first element of the result should be:

```
0 => ['1a','2a','3a','4a','5a'],
1 => ['1a','2b','3a','4a','5a'],
```

I don't have to get doubloons like:

```
0 => ['1a','2a','3a','4a','5a'],
1 => ['1a','2b','3a','4a','5a'],
2 => ['2a','1a','3a','4a','5a']
```

With key 0 and key 2 similar..

I Don't know if this is clear enough.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays)

Comment: Yes Already seen but doesn't seem to work well..

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the php pear library math combinatoric:http://pear.php.net/package/Math_Combinatorics.