# Unique strings based on multi dimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

> The answer can be found here: [How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays)

I need the logic on how to create unique strings looking like this:

```
alusion alusion ails
alusion alusion ainu
alusion apoints ails
```

I have a multi dimensional array as input.
The key in each dimension represents the position of the word in the final string.

```
$array = (
  [0] = array('alusion', 'apoints'),
  [1] = array('alusion', 'apoints'),
  [2] = array('ails', 'ainu')
);
```

Comment: Look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays

Comment: That worked perfectly!