# general loop in java generating all possible strings

Tags: java

I am having difficulty creating some general for loops on my own (my code is in java). Imagine I have **M** number of arraylists of strings that each arraylist **s_i** has **x_i** members. I want to generate all possible strings such that the first part of string is from first set, the second part of string is from second set and ...

For example, below, there are 3 lists (which is unknown at time of programming):

`|s_0| = x_0 = 3: [a1, a2, a3]`

`|s_1| = x_1 = 5: [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5]`

`|s_2| = x_2 = 2: [c1, c2]`

I want to generate these strings (order is not important):

strings: `["a1 b1 c1", "a1 b1 c2", "a1 b2 c1", ...., "a3 b5 c2"]`

Comment: You want all permutations of them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays)

Comment: Hint: Define a cross product between two sets and generalize to three.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Guava Sets](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct(java.util.Set...)). For example this will give all combinations `AAA`, `AAB`,`...`,`CCC`.

```
final Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("A");
set.add("B");
set.add("C");
final Set<List<String>> sets = Sets.cartesianProduct(set, set, set);
```

In your case you will have to pass `s_0`, `s_1`, `s_2` for the parameters.