# PHP: Create combinations of array values from bottom up

Tags: php

I have to get all the combinations of values between n number of arrays.

Here is an example:

Filters: F1, F2, F3 contain values V1, V2, V3 the desire outcome is to have a massive array of all possible combinations in a such way:

**V1^F1, V1^F2**

**V1^F1, V1^F2, V1^F3**,

**V1^F1, V1^F2, V2^F3**

and so on.

The rules are that I don't need to combine the values inside a filter **only** with the  values with the other arrays.

```
<?php

$filterA = array('blue', 'red', 'black');
$filterB = array('s', 'm', 'l');
$filterC = array('men', 'woman');


$filters[] = $filterA;
$filters[] = $filterB;
$filters[] = $filterC;

var_dump(combinations($filters));

function combinations($arrays, $i = 0)
{
     if (!isset($arrays[$i])) 
     {
            return array();
     }
        // Exit Conditions;
        if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) 
        {
            return $arrays[$i];
        }

         // get combinations from subsequent arrays
        $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

        $result = array();

        // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
        foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) 
        {
            foreach ($tmp as $t) 
            {
                $result[] = is_array($t) ? array_merge(array($v), $t) : array($v, $t);
            }
        }

        return $result;
}
```

The following code produced almost the desired code however it misses to print out the 1st variation which is with less values.

Any suggestions to modify the code to get the desired outcome?

Comment: why not V1^F1 only ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays

Comment: Why not simply use 3 nested loops: https://3v4l.org/HoFTg or https://3v4l.org/MhZFE

Comment: Because I don't know how many arrays there will be as a filters. This is just an example. Recursion is preferred to be used here.