# Sorting 'key=>value' pair multi-dimensional arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am creating a site and I am trying to do a few complicated things with arrays to get it to work.

It is for an e-commerce site and each product on my site can have a number of attributes. I am trying to get each combination of attributes to do the pricing for them seperately.

First I get an array of the attribute ids (`$attribute_id_array`) and the query the database for the options for that array.

So if one attribute was colors the options here would be red,green,blue,etc,. or size would be small,medium,large,etc,. These are then stored in a new array (`$attribute_arrays`).

I then go through these to get every combination of attributes the product can have and sort these into a new array again (`$new_attributes_array`).

I then loop through this and create a price form for each combination.

```
$attribute_arrays = [];
foreach($attribute_id_array as $attribute_id){
    $params = [$attribute_id];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM attributes WHERE id=?";
    $attributeResult = DB::run($sql,$params);
    while($row = $attributeResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        array_push($attribute_arrays,$row);
    }
}
var_dump($attribute_arrays);
function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }
    $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);
    $result = array();
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                array($v, $t);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
$new_attributes_array = combinations($attribute_arrays);
var_dump($new_attributes_array);
```

This is all working fine except I want to be able to get the keys for all of the key value pairs so I can reference it back to my database.

The way it comes out at the moment is like this:

$attribute_id_array:

```
array (size=2)
  1 => string '5' (length=1)
  2 => string '7' (length=1)
```

$attribute_arrays:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute1' => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
      'attribute2' => string 'Gated' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute1' => string '3 metres' (length=8)
      'attribute2' => string '6 metres' (length=8)
```

$new_attributes_array:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
      1 => string '3 metres' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
      1 => string '6 metres' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Gated' (length=5)
      1 => string '3 metres' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Gated' (length=5)
      1 => string '6 metres' (length=8)
```

Is there a way to get it so that the key will be similar in format to:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      5-attribute1 => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
      7-attribute1 => string '3 metres' (length=8)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      5-attribute1 => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
      7-attribute2 => string '6 metres' (length=8)
```

### Edit

So I changed the line `array_push($attribute_arrays,$row);` to `$attribute_arrays[$attribute_id] = $row;`.

This now means that `$attribute_arrays` now has the`$attribute_id` variable as the key like so:

```
array (size=2)
  5 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute1' => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
      'attribute2' => string 'Gated' (length=5)
  7 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute1' => string '3 metres' (length=8)
      'attribute2' => string '6 metres' (length=8)
```

This now means my other function for getting the combinations won't work as it is  using the `$i` variable as the index for the array starting at '0'.

Found another function online to sort it here [How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays):

```
function combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $property => $property_values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $result_item) {
            foreach ($property_values as $property_key => $property_value) {
                $tmp[] = $result_item + array($property_key => $property_value);
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

However, this doesn't do exactly as I want and I end up with this:

```
array (size=4)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'attribute1' => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
  1 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute1' => string 'Step Through Bars' (length=17)
      'attribute2' => string '6 metres' (length=8)
  2 => 
    array (size=2)
      'attribute2' => string 'Gated' (length=5)
      'attribute1' => string '3 metres' (length=8)
  3 => 
    array (size=1)
      'attribute2' => string 'Gated' (length=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this as your combinations function

modified code taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/4688876)

```
function combinations($arrays) {
    $result = array(array());
    foreach ($arrays as $key => $values) {
        $tmp = array();
        foreach ($result as $item) {
            foreach ($values as $k=>$value) {
                $tmp[] = array_merge($item, array($key.'-'.$k => $value));
            }
        }
        $result = $tmp;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: You're a hero!!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using while on following line

```
while($row = $attributeResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
```

Use foreach loop to get key paired value. e.g

```
foreach($databaseFetchedRecord as $mykey=>$myvalue)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, however, those rows in my DB actually have a column for the id and name as well as empty rows as some attributes may have more options than others so my actual code for that part has a few extra lines: `while($row = $attributeResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
 unset($row['id']);
 unset($row['name']);
 $row = array_diff($row, [""]);
 array_push($attribute_arrays,$row);
}`so I am not sure how to go about this using the way you describe.