# PHP string expansion

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string composed by many letters, at some point, one letter from a group can be used and this is represented by letters enclosed in []. I need to expand these letters into its actual strings.

From this:

`$str = 'ABCCDF[GH]IJJ[KLM]'`

To this:

```
$sub[0] = 'ABCCDFGIJJK';
$sub[1] = 'ABCCDFHIJJK';
$sub[2] = 'ABCCDFGIJJL';
$sub[3] = 'ABCCDFHIJJL';
$sub[4] = 'ABCCDFGIJJM';
$sub[5] = 'ABCCDFHIJJM';
```

UPDATE:

Thanks to @Barmar for the very valuable suggestions.

My final solution is:

```
$str = '[GH]DF[IK]TF[ADF]';

function parseString(string $str) : array
{
    $i = 0;
    $is_group = false;
    $sub = array();
    $chars = preg_split('//', $str, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

    foreach ($chars as $key => $value)
    {
        if(ctype_alpha($value))
        {
            if($is_group){
                $sub[$i][] = $value;
            } else {
                if(!isset($sub[$i][0])){
                    $sub[$i][0] = $value;
                } else {
                    $sub[$i][0] .= $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $is_group = !$is_group;
            ++$i;
        }
    }
    return $sub;
}
```

The recommended function for combinations is (check the related post):

```
function array_cartesian_product($arrays)
{
    $result = array();
    $arrays = array_values($arrays);
    $sizeIn = sizeof($arrays);
    $size = $sizeIn > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    foreach ($arrays as $array)
        $size = $size * sizeof($array);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
        $result[$i] = array();
        for ($j = 0; $j < $sizeIn; $j++)
            array_push($result[$i], current($arrays[$j]));
        for ($j = ($sizeIn - 1); $j >= 0; $j--) {
            if (next($arrays[$j]))
                break;
            elseif (isset($arrays[$j]))
                reset($arrays[$j]);
        }
    }
    return $result;
}
```

Check the solution with:

```
$combinations = array_cartesian_product(parseString($str));
$sub = array_map('implode', $combinations);
var_dump($sub);
```

Comment: Turn the strings in square brackets into arrays. Then get all the combinations of the arrays.

Comment: What are you doing with the `sub`s later? Maybe just using `$str` in a regex context would work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to I can split match letter in string PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54472641/how-to-i-can-split-match-letter-in-string-php)

Comment: @barmar Thanks for your advice but is not totally clear for me.

What you suggest is to break the string in arrays like this

    $str[0] = 'ABCCDF'
    $str[1] = 'G'
    $str[2] = 'H'
    $str[3] = 'IJJ'
    $str[4] = 'K'
    $str[5] = 'L'
    $str[6] = 'M'

... and then do the permutations?

I think I can do the arrys, could you please give me some advice for the permutations?

Comment: @user3783243

I need the expanded strings to search inside thos strings, for example, I want to know if `'DFIJ'` belogns to this rule

Comment: What is the rule? Where does `DFIJ ` come from? Also why does another user have the same code as you?

Comment: Hello, @user3783243 The `DFIJ` comes from the question about what I am going to do with these expanded strings. I want to verify the existence of many random strings inside this expanded strings. That's an example. Other could be `AADD` or `ABCM` I think the best way is to expand the strings instead to do some regular expression search.
I posted this question in another two forums. Probably someone is trying to solve my question but is not me.

Comment: None of those match the expanded strings though. How do they relate?

Comment: @user3783243 Probably was a wrong example. I'll try to make a better one: Suppose I want to check what of this strings is included (as a partial or full match) in one of the expanded strings. Then `CDFHIJ` is a match with $sub[1], `ABCCDFH` is a match with $sub[1], $sub[3] and $sub[5] and `ABCM` doesn't match.

Comment: `CDFHIJ` matches 1, 3, and 5 as well. Are the constants optional, e.g. `ABCCDF` and `IJJ` may/may not be present? Because I wouldn't normally say `CDFHIJ` == `ABCCDFHIJJK`.

Comment: Yes, I need the expanded strings to check if a random string is CONTAINED in some way in at least one (1) of these expanded strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your string into a 2-dimensional array. The parts outside brackets become single-element arrays, while each bracketed trings becomes an array of single characters. So your string would become:

```
$array = 
    array(array('ABCCDF'),
          array('G', 'H', 'I'),
          array('IJJ'),
          array('K', 'L', 'M'));
```

Then you just need to compute all the combinations of those arrays; use one of the answers at [How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays). Finally, you concatenate each of the resulting arrays with `implode` to get an array of strings.

```
$combinations = combinations($array);
$sub = array_map('implode', $combinations);
```