# How to I can split match letter in string PHP

Tags: php

I have string :

```
$string = 'ABCCDF[GH]IJJ[KLM]';
```

How to i get string 'GH' and 'KLM' in php

I think i will use preg_split, but I know not more about reg. Plz help me.

Comment: What does mean "split" for you? What do you want to get in the end?

Comment: I want have result at: $result[0] = 'GH'; $result[1] = 'KLM';

Comment: Do you want to get all matches between `[` and `]` chars in the string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this;

```php
>>> $string = 'ABCCDF[GH]IJJ[KLM]';
=> "ABCCDF[GH]IJJ[KLM]"
>>> preg_match_all('/\[(\w+)\]/', $string, $matches);
=> 2
```

`$matches` will look like below.

```
   [
     [
       "[GH]",
       "[KLM]",
     ],
     [
       "GH",
       "KLM",
     ],
   ]
```

Comment: this guys asks for a permutation, regexp here is a minor headache

Comment: and how to get ABCCDF and IJJ. thanks I dont know regexp, I fail