# PHP - How to output combination of elements from array?

Tags: php

I have an array :

```
$names = array("Jim", "Jane", "Bob", "Susan", "Ralph");
```

And I want to have calculate combinations for 3 elements.

The output is something like that:

```
Jim, Jane, Bob
Jim, Jane, Susan
Jim, Jane, Ralph
Jim, Bob, Susan
Jim, Bob, Ralph
Jim, Susan, Ralph
Jane, Bob, Susan
Jane, Bob, Ralph
Jane, Susan, Ralph
Bob, Susan, Ralph
```

The expected output has 10 different combinations. I have been thinking how to achieve this but have no idea how to do this. Please help, thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays)

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more about the restriction of the combinations? I see a total of X names which should be filled in groups of size Y? I guess they need to be unique per group? Is the number of total groups also restricted (Z) or should it be the maximum possible?

Comment: @ChristophKluge the names should be unique per group , using the math formula `r!(n – r)!` , therefore `3!(5 – 3)!` the numbers of group should be exactly 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The algorithm is pretty straight forward. You can simply use a while statement to loop over the remained entries after you shift the first element, and then use 2 other loops to append the remained names in order:

```
$names = ["Jim", "Jane", "Bob", "Susan", "Ralph"];
$result = [];

while (count($names) > 2) {
    $currentName = array_shift($names);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($names) - 1; $i++) {
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($names); $j++) {
            $result[] = implode(', ', [$currentName, $names[$i], $names[$j]]);
        }
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

The result would be:

```
array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(14) "Jim, Jane, Bob"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "Jim, Jane, Susan"
  [2]=>
  string(16) "Jim, Jane, Ralph"
  [3]=>
  string(15) "Jim, Bob, Susan"
  [4]=>
  string(15) "Jim, Bob, Ralph"
  [5]=>
  string(17) "Jim, Susan, Ralph"
  [6]=>
  string(16) "Jane, Bob, Susan"
  [7]=>
  string(16) "Jane, Bob, Ralph"
  [8]=>
  string(18) "Jane, Susan, Ralph"
  [9]=>
  string(17) "Bob, Susan, Ralph"
}
```