# Combine three strings (day, month, year) and calculate next date (PHP)

Tags: php

What would be the best way to combine the following strings and determine when the next date would be. The strings are pulled from the database in this format.

```
<?php
 $date  = '2020-10-30';  // Current Date

 $year  = '2020,2021';   // 2 Years
 $month = '02,04,07,10'; // 4 Months
 $day   = '28,29,30';    // 3 Days

 // Total of 24 Combos || Excluding Current Date | Next Date Would Be: 2021-02-28
?>
```

My theory was to combine them as an array and determine the next date from there. However I'm having trouble getting to that point.

The code below was from this question.
[How to generate in PHP all combinations of items in multiple arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567082/how-to-generate-in-php-all-combinations-of-items-in-multiple-arrays)

```
<?php
function combinations($arrays, $i = 0) {
    if (!isset($arrays[$i])) {
        return array();
    }
    if ($i == count($arrays) - 1) {
        return $arrays[$i];
    }

    // get combinations from subsequent arrays
    $tmp = combinations($arrays, $i + 1);

    $result = array();

    // concat each array from tmp with each element from $arrays[$i]
    foreach ($arrays[$i] as $v) {
        foreach ($tmp as $t) {
            $result[] = is_array($t) ? 
                array_merge(array($v), $t) :
                array($v, $t);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

print_r(
    combinations(
        array(
            array($day), 
            array($month), 
            array($year)
        )
    )
);

?>
```

Which outputs:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28,29,30 [1] => 02,04,07,10 [2] => 2020,2021 ) )
```

Next I tried stripping the commas and splitting the strings.

```
$day = str_replace(",", "", $day); 
$day = str_split($day, 2);
  
$month = str_replace(",", "", $month); 
$month = str_split($month, 2);
  
$year = str_replace(",", "", $year); 
$year = str_split($year, 4);
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 28 [1] => 29 [2] => 30 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => 02 [1] => 04 [2] => 07 [3] => 10 ) [2] => 2020 [3] => 2021 ) )
```

I'm now at a loss as to how I would go about determining what the next date would be.
Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with MySQL

Comment: Ended up being a slim line version of the overall script. The info is pulled from a database, as mentioned in the second line. But you are right, since I didn't end up posting that segment of code, I shall remove the tags for you. ;)

Comment: I think that the best way would be transforming the dates in Unix timestamp with `strtotime()` and then compare the strings with simple operators `<=` or `>=`, hope this makes sense.

Comment: The end result will be saved as a Unix timestamp, but I'm still not sure the best way to work out all the combos of dates in the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t build any combinations upfront - just loop through them, until you either find a next date, or determined that there isn’t one.

Loop over the years, inside loop over the months, inside loop over the days.

Concatenate all three values with `-` in between them, and check if that combination is greater than your input date. If so, set that value as the `$next_date`, and break out of all three loop levels.

Afterwards, you either have a next date value in $next_date - or still `null`, which means a next date could not be determined for the given input values.

```
$date  = '2020-10-30';  // Current Date

$year  = '2020,2021';   // 2 Years
$month = '02,04,07,10'; // 4 Months
$day   = '28,29,30';    // 3 Days

$years = explode(',', $year);
$months = explode(',', $month);
$days = explode(',', $day);

$next_date = null;
foreach($years as $y) {
  foreach($months as $m) {
    foreach($days as $d) {
      $temp = $y.'-'.$m.'-'.$d;
      if($temp > $date) {
        $next_date = $temp;
        break 3;
      }
    }
  }
}
if($next_date) {
  echo 'next date is: ' . $next_date;
}
else {
  echo 'there is no next date in the given range.';
}
```

Comment: Oh wow! That works perfectly. Thank you so much. Having you as a friend would have saved me a lot of time and a headache! Nothing like what I was thinking... Thanks for explaining it all very well too. Makes perfect sense.