# How to avoid memory error when building an exhaustive list of options?

Tags: php, out-of-memory

I am attempting to build a list of all possible sequences of mod12 int values. This will then be filtered in various ways depending on context. One use case would use a lower modulo but the function should handle up to 12.

- Each value can be in the range 0…11.
- The length of each sequence is configurable.

I thought by starting with the first pattern (an array of `0` values) I could:

1. iterate each position
2. iterate each pattern
3. iterate the range of values
4. append the current pattern with the current position updated to the current value

This scales memory usage very quickly and i'm unable to build patterns longer than a few positions. eg a length of 6 produces a memory exhaustion of 536870912 bytes (0.5GB)

I thought of using generators but I assume thats not possible with the way I build upon the existing list of patterns.

```php
/**
 * All sequences of mod12 values.
 */
function melodyPatterns(int $length = 8, int $mod = 12)
 {
    $patterns = [array_pad([], $length, 0)];
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
     {
        foreach ($patterns as $pattern)
         {
            for ($v = 1; $v < $mod; $v++)
             {
                $newp = $pattern;
                $newp[$i] = $v;
                $patterns[] = $newp;
             }
         }
     }
    return $patterns;
 }

$patterns = melodyPatterns(6);

// output to check results
foreach ($patterns as $pattern)
 {
    echo implode(' ', $pattern) . "\n";
 }
echo count($patterns)."\n";
```

Is there another way to do this with generators or possibly a temporary cache file or different algorithm? my memory limit is half a gigabyte.

Comment: Just echo each pattern immediately instead of storing it in an array for later output?

Comment: Typically for something like this, if results need to be stored, I would use a loop like you are, but `fopen()` a file handle and `fwrite()` to it in the loop, putting one result on each line. 

If you need it all in memory at once, then you'll need to modify your php.ini settings to allow PHP to use more memory.

Comment: What are you doing with all these sequences? The time taken to do anything with them will probably be prohibitive.

Comment: @Barmar most probable use case would be to filter them

Comment: A generator would be typically used for this.

Comment: @ADyson the output was just to check results, the array would be useless if i just output it.

Comment: A generator would work, but maybe you could pass the filtering function into the loop that produces the list.

Comment: @Olivier I couldn't find a way to incorporate generators in this kind of algorithm

Comment: @Barmar excellent but there would be a case where the filter accepts all patterns, then i still have the memory issue

Comment: can generators be used recursively? i'm exploring this now

Comment: I don't know what mod12 is, but the total number of combinations is x^y, where `x` is the # of symbols to pick from and `y` is the # of positions. Pick a calculator and do the maths, because if you're dealing with an insane amount of data, running out of memory is not going the real problem. 8^12 alone is 68,719,476,736 elements.

Comment: Then I go back to my original question: What are you going to do with the filtered data if there's so much of it?

Comment: If the sequence order doesn't matter: see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70800936/12763954).

Comment: I haven't got that far yet, use them individually i guess, record each one that has been used and pick one that hasn't next time. one case will take a few patterns and put them in sequence (or a pattern of patterns). if the data is too big then it can't be stored in memory and will also be hard to sort through or filter, makes sense, I should have realized the math. most common cases will use 3-7 as the max value (modulo) but 8 would be a pretty standard length. i was more interested in if this kind of thing can be done because my programming isn't that strong.

Comment: @Barmar like generate randomly could work, storing used patterns for reference, then if the returned pattern exists i just generate another one.